# Problema com Latex Figuras Pulando paragrafos

Tags: latex

Olá, a um pouco mais de um mês comecei a utilizar o Latex para escrever meu tcc, de uns dias pra cá comecei a inserir figuras e estava tudo ocorrendo bem, até que derrepente ao inserir mais figuras, algumas que estavam inclusas antes ficaram desestruturadas. Simplesmente começaram a pular paragrafos, pensei que talves fosse alguma \ perdida no meio do texto mas não achei nada parecido.

Tentarei explicar o que acontece. O que ocorre é da seguinte forma:

Fonte: Gonzales e woods (2007)

[Paragrafo]

[Imagem]

A imagem simplesmente pula um paragrafo seguinte sem razão quando na verdade deveria aparecer em cima da fonte. Eis o codigo da figura abaixo:

```
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \caption{Exemplo de Histograma de uma imagem em escala de cinza.} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{Figuras/Figura_3_ExemploHistograma.png} \\
\end{figure}
Fonte: Gonzalez e Woods (2007). \\
```

Alguém saberia possiveis problemas que estariam ocasionando isto? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 5):

Experimente usar a opção `[H]` Após o `\begin{figure}`. Tente ainda o código abaixo:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \IBGEtab{
        \caption{Exemplo de Histograma de uma imagem em escala de cinza.}
        \label{GrayScale}
    }
    {\includegraphics[width=9.5cm]{Figuras/Figura_3_ExemploHistograma.png}}
    {Fonte: Gonzalez e Woods (2007).}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Eu já votei com +1 porque a resposta é mesmo muito boa. Mas seria bom explicar ao AP o porquê dessas decisões (o `h` usado para indicar o posicionamento da figura como "here" [aqui], e o texto "Fonte: ..." dentro do escopo do elemento flutuante). :) P.S.: Não entendi o/a motivo/necessidade do comando `\IBGEtab`.

Comment: @LuizVieira, vi referência a um IBGEtab no pacote abntex2  (tambem designado por absurdas normas tecnicas...) que reformata a caption de modo a ficar conforme um norma (que de um modo geral acho feioso)...

Comment: Avelino, gostei +1

Answer (score 3):

Esta resposta é na realidade um comentário mais comprido...

Como o @Avelino muito bem disse, `\begin{figure}[H]` pode ser usado para 
forçar a que uma figura seja inserida nesse exacto ponto. Este funcionamento
força que figuras ou tabelas deixem de ser corpos flutuantes.

No entanto **isso é normalmente mau** para a construção de texto de qualidade:
quase sempre gera espaços em branco adicionais (gera textos com mais páginas e com pior aspecto).

Normalmente convem (desculpa o paternalismo):

1. usar figuras de dimensão pequena
2. deixar as figuras flutuar e referi-las pela sua label (ex: na fig. \label{grayScale} apresenta-se ......)
3. forçar posicionamentos em casos especiais...

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado a todos pelas respostas, e peço desculpas pela demora a responder,  bom no final acabou q a solução foi o que vc disse ae em cima, o tamanho das figuras estavam muito grandes em relação ao texto da pagina, isso fazia com que a imagem pulasse partes do texto. A solução q encontrei quando nao podia diminuir o tamanho das imagens foi utilizar a função /pagebreak para quebra de página. Agradeço novamente pelas resposta de todos.

Comment: @YuriPires se acha que esta resposta é a solução para o seu problema, não se esqueça de a marcar com o visto de certa.